# django rest framework - POST when Primary Key is also a Foreign Key - "This field is required." OR 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an issue doing a POST to the following models -

```
class Tskmst(models.Model):
    tskmst_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='tskmst_id', primary_key=True)
    tskmst_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tskmst_desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmst_type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(Owner, db_column='owner_id')
    tskmst_public = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    tskmst_lstchgtm = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    nodmst_id = models.ForeignKey(Nodmst, db_column='nodmst_id', blank=True, null=True)
    servicemst_id = models.ForeignKey(Servicemst, db_column='servicemst_id', related_name='Tskmst_Servicemst_id', blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tskmst_name   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tskmst'

class Tskmail(models.Model):
    tskmail_id = models.ForeignKey(Tskmst, db_column='tskmail_id', related_name='action_email_details', primary_key=True)
    tskmail_to_int = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_to_ext = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_subject = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_memo = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    tskmail_priority = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tskmail_attach = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tskmail'
```

On a GET it works fine with a reverse relationship - here's my serializers

```
class ActionMailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tskmail
        resource_name = 'tskmail'
        fields = ('tskmail_id', 'tskmail_to_int', 'tskmail_to_ext', 'tskmail_subject', 'tskmail_memo',
                'tskmail_priority', 'tskmail_attach')

class ActionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_name = serializers.Field(source='owner_id.owner_name')
    nodmst_name = serializers.Field(source='nodmst_id.nodmst_name')
    servicemst_name = serializers.Field(source='servicemst_id.servicemst_name')
    action_email_details = ActionMailSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = Tskmst
        resource_name = 'tskmst'
        depth = 1
        fields = ('tskmst_id', 'tskmst_name', 'tskmst_desc', 'tskmst_type', 'owner_name', 'tskmst_public',
                'tskmst_lstchgtm', 'nodmst_name', 'servicemst_name', 'action_email_details')
```

But on a POST it complains on the following during the validation phase -

```
{
    "action_email_details": [
        {
            "tskmail_id": "This field is required."
        }
    ]
}
```

The tskmail_id is definitely there and I have no issue with other models where the PK is different than the FK being used for the reverse relation.  How do I get around this?

If I change my serializer code on the reverse relationship to be this -

```
class ActionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_name = serializers.Field(source='owner_id.owner_name')
    nodmst_name = serializers.Field(source='nodmst_id.nodmst_name')
    servicemst_name = serializers.Field(source='servicemst_id.servicemst_name')
    action_email_details = ActionMailSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Tskmst
        resource_name = 'tskmst'
        depth = 1
        fields = ('tskmst_id', 'tskmst_name', 'tskmst_desc', 'tskmst_type', 'owner_name', 'tskmst_public',
                'tskmst_lstchgtm', 'nodmst_name', 'servicemst_name', 'action_email_details')
```

It then gives another message on POST - RelatedManager object is not iterable.

```
Traceback:
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  400.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  397.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Tidal\API\views.py" in put
  193.         if serializer.is_valid():
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in is_valid
  553.         return not self.errors
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in errors
  545.                 ret = self.from_native(data, files)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in from_native
  996.         instance = super(ModelSerializer, self).from_native(data, files)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in from_native
  368.             attrs = self.restore_fields(data, files)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in restore_fields
  283.                 field.field_from_native(data, files, field_name, reverted_data)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in field_from_native
  472.                 if serializer.is_valid():
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in is_valid
  553.         return not self.errors
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in errors
  521.                     identities = [self.get_identity(self.to_native(obj)) for obj in objects]

Exception Type: TypeError at /deploy/action/
Exception Value: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've given your `ForeignKey` fields the same name as their `db_column`? The usual convention would be to name the field `tskmail`, in which case `tskmail_id` would be the default `db_column` value - I suspect your problems arise from this.

Comment: It's a legacy DB hence needing to set the column name.  Going by your suggestion I removed the `db_column='tskmail_id'` and set the field as `tskmail`.  Trying a POST again it failed with `KeyError: 'tskmail_id'`

Comment: You probably also have to update your serializer to refer to `tskmail` - `tskmail_id` becomes an implementation option that you only refer to if you want to read the actual integer FK, or set it outside of a form context. I would expect the serializer classes to work correctly with FK fields by abstracting that detail away.

Comment: Oh right, Django gets unhappy if it doesn't have an integer declared PK field. That makes your situation hard. As an alternative to your described workaround I might try leaving `tskmail_id` declared purely as an integer PK field and declare `tskmail` as a ForeignKey with `db_column='tskmail_id'`. Or look at how subclassed models work behind the scenes, they might have a PK field that is also a FK to the parent table.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If you want to post as an answer I'll accept it it's got me around the issue I was having.

Comment: I've been hesitant since I'm not 100% sure what the fix is, I just have some theories on where the problems come from, but I guess if it helped that's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't like it if you don't have an integer PK field. I think it also runs into conflicts if the name of a `ForeignKey` field is the same as its `db_column`. In this case the legacy DB design makes it hard. In addition to the workaround you describe:

> I think I may have "tricked" the system. what I did was create a new field called `tskmail = models.IntegerField(db_column='tskmail_id', primary_key=True)` and I removed the `primary_key=True` from the ForiegnKey so essentially I'm displaying the field twice.

I might try leaving `tskmail_id` declared as an integer PK field and declare `tskmail` as a `ForeignKey` with `db_column='tskmail_id'` (or leave `db_column` unspecified so that default choice applies). It might be worth checking how Django implements subclassed non-abstract models - they might have a PK field that is also a FK to the parent table.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually went with your suggestion as it allows me to understand easier where the PK and FK references are.